# FaceBook UI is not populating multiple friends selected

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using an FB.ui 'apprequests' method to select friends,and it is happening. Then i am redirecting from there to a Send Message pop up (FB.ui 'send' method). Before, the 'To:' section in the pop up was populating multiple friends. But now its showing only the first selected friend.Your suggestions are welcome.

The code looks like this,

```
$('#sendinvite').click(function () 
    {
            FB.ui
        ({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: "sds"
        },send_Message);
    });

    function send_Message(response) 
    {
    var eventName = 'Event Name';
    var varMessage ="You are invited for " + eventName;
        console.log(response.to);
                FB.ui
        ({
                method: 'send',
                to: response.to,
                name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
                description: varMessage,
                link: 'http://www.techvantagesystems.com'
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, Facebook has changed this behavior recently, and now allows only **one** pre-filled friend in the `to` option of `send` dialog. Ofcourse the user can select more friends once the dialog has come up.

A lot of developers are asking this question, check [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/314701778595814).